# NESTJS Kafka, How to start the microservice when broker is not available

Tags: javascript, typescript, apache-kafka, nestjs, kafkajs

I am using the NestJS microservice with Kafka.

Issue: Let's say at server startup the Kafka is not available, the service will crash as the server is not able to connect to the service.

Expected Behaviour: I will like the service to get started even if the Kafka is not available. And in the background the library should keep checking on the connection and connect to brokers when they are available.

Code:

```
 app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
      kafkaConfig,
    );
```

We are using `EventPattern` Decorators.

`@nestjs/microservices "9.0.11`

Would appreciate any help